# How can I use a Cursor to retrieve the name of a table?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am using a `Cursor` to retrieve the name of the tables of a specific value in my database. The problem is that I am not sure how to use it.

Normally, I would do:

```
Cursor c = myDbHelper.getSelectedData(value);
int id = c.getColumnIndex("ENGLISH_NAME");
```

But, this code would loop through the records of the column call "ENGLISH_NAME"

How can I use it to retrieve the names of the tables?

Here is the `Cursor`

```
public Cursor selectTablesFromSearch(String value){

String selectQuery = " SELECT TableName" +
                         " ,       ENGLISH_NAME " +
                         " FROM    (" +
                         "         SELECT \'BABY_FOODS\' AS TableName" +
                                 " ,      ENGLISH_NAME " +
                                 " FROM BABY_FOODS " +
                                 " UNION ALL " +
                                 " SELECT \'BAKED_PRODUCTS_AND_CORN_TORTILLAS\'" +
                                 " ,      ENGLISH_NAME " +
                                 " FROM BAKED_PRODUCTS_AND_CORN_TORTILLAS" +
                                 " UNION ALL " +
                                 " SELECT \'BEEF_PRODUCTS\'" +
                                 " ,      ENGLISH_NAME " +
                                 " FROM BEEF_PRODUCTS" +
                                 " ) AS SubQueryAlias " +
                                 " WHERE ENGLISH_NAME IN (\'" + value + "\')";

return myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use the `query()` provided by Android's `SQLiteDatabase`. You typically store the name of the table in a `public static String`.

Comment: I think he does need to use rawQuery here, but honestly I'm not quite sure what's going on in this code

Comment: Yes, I have the `static String[]` of the tables. But, my implementation selects data from any of those tables. At the end, I would need a structure like a `HashMap<String, String>` to associate the 'ENGLISH_NAME' value with the 'TableName'

Comment: I also, understand that a `Cursor` traverses the records of the tables. So, Is there a structure to traverse the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (c.moveFirst()) {
    do {
        String value = c.getString(0);
    } while (c.moveNext());
}
```